# Why am I not able to get the last number from list using binary search?

Tags: python, binary-search

I've written a code to find the index place of the number asked by user. I am getting the answer for all numbers except the last number (after sorting the list) which is 92 in this case, below is the code. Please guide what is wrong here.

```
# Python program to implement binary search

list = [54, 67, 85, 33, 92, 74]
list.sort()
print(f'Given list is: {list}')

low = 0
upp = len(list)-1
mid = (low + upp) // 2

num = list.index(int(input('Enter number: ')))

while num != mid:
    mid = (low + upp) // 2
    if num < mid:
        upp = mid
        mid = (low + upp) // 2
    else:
        if num > mid:
            low = mid
            mid = (low + upp) // 2
print(f'found at {mid} index')
```

Comment: `num = list.index(int(input('Enter number: ')))` uses the actual index to calculate the index.  That's not what you want.  Also shouldn't use the built-in `list` as a variable name.

Comment: `num = list.index(int(input('Enter number: ')))` is getting you the index directly, with `O(n)` search. The rest of your code isn't even looking at your `list` (which should *not* be named `list`, since it cuts off access to the built-in `list` constructor). The rest of your code is confusingly binary searching for the index it already knows (it's in `num`).

Comment: Also, presumably `upp` should be initialized to `len(list)`, not `len(list) - 1` (I haven't analyzed things thoroughly, but most binary search algorithms use an exclusive index for the upper bound; the fact you don't, and fail only when searching for the largest value, indicates you probably *should* be using `len(list)`).

Comment: Hint: does it not seem strange to you, that none of the code inside the loop does anything involving the list?

Answer (score 2):

Your described problem is that the algorithm you're using is intended to have `upp` as the *exclusive* upper bound; by initializing it to `len(list)-1`, you can't find the uppermost index at all. Change `upp = len(list)-1` to `upp = len(list)` and the code "works" (it just doesn't do anything useful).

Your other problems are:

1. `num = list.index(int(input('Enter number: ')))` is getting you the index directly, with `O(n)` search under the hood, eliminating the benefit of binary searching. The rest of your code isn't even looking at your `list`, you're just doing `O(log n)` work to find a `mid` equal to `num`, when `mid = num` would achieve the same result with no search involved (no *additional* search beyond what `list.index` was doing anyway).
2. You named your variable `list`, which means the `list` constructor is unavailable; this is a bad idea (even if it doesn't break anything here).
3. (Not an issue in the current code, but an issue trying to fix #1) Your code experiences an infinite loop when the value being searched for is not in the `list` (in your current code, the `list.index` call handles that by raising an exception, but as noted, if you use `list.index`, you gain no benefit from binary search at all).

For #1, you wanted to accept the input without a `list.index` call:

```
num = int(input('Enter number: '))
```

then change each comparison between `num` and `mid` to compare `num` and `list[mid]` (or `mylist[mid]` or whatever better name you use for the `list`), so `num` is always the *value* being searched for, `mid` is the current index being searched, and `list[mid]` is the value at that index. You also need to improve your search so it stops when the value you're searching for doesn't exist in the `list` (left as exercise; there's thousands upon thousands of examples of hand-implemented binary search, in pseudocode and Python, out there), rather than looping forever.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a binary search implementation that may help you to see where you've gone wrong:

```
list_ = sorted([54, 67, 85, 33, 92, 74])

def bsearch(lst, x):
    L = 0
    R = len(lst) - 1
    while L <= R:
        m = (L + R) // 2
        if (v := lst[m]) == x:
            return m
        if v < x:
            L = m + 1
        else:
            R = m - 1
    return -1

while (x := input('Enter a number to search for (q to quit): ')) not in 'Qq':
    try:
        if (i := bsearch(list_, int(x))) < 0:
            print('Not found')
        else:
            print(f'Found at {i}')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```